# aws cli: update-kubeconfig not working as expected

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, command-line-interface, amazon-eks

I am trying to update kubeconfig file using the below mentioned CLI

```
aws eks update-kubeconfig --name EKS_cluster
```

It is giving me this error

```
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
aws: error: argument operation: Invalid choice, valid choices are:

create-cluster                           | delete-cluster
describe-cluster                         | list-clusters
help
```

The was cli version I am using is

```
aws-cli/1.15.58 Python/3.5.2 Linux/5.3.0-1030-aws botocore/1.10.57
```

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs of creating a kubeconfig for Amazon EKS [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/create-kubeconfig.html)

> Ensure that you have version 1.16.156 or later of the AWS CLI
> installed.

Clearly this is because of older version(1.15.58) of CLI. Upgrading the CLI should solve this issue.

Also now the CLI has got version 2 which you can install from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-install.html)

Answer (score 1):

Your version of the AWS-CLI needs to be updated. At the very least you need to be running AWS-CLI version 1.16.156 as mentioned in the [AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/create-kubeconfig.html).

> Amazon EKS uses the aws eks get-token command, available in version 1.16.156 or later of the AWS CLI or the AWS IAM Authenticator for Kubernetes with kubectl for cluster authentication.

You'll also need to make sure you have [AWS IAM Authenticator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/install-aws-iam-authenticator.html) installed in order to authenticate using roles.

> Download the Amazon EKS-vended aws-iam-authenticator binary from Amazon S3. To download the ARM version, change amd64 to arm64 before running the command. `curl -o aws-iam-authenticator https://amazon-eks.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/1.17.7/2020-07-08/bin/linux/amd64/aws-iam-authenticator`

> Apply execute permissions to the binary. `chmod +x ./aws-iam-authenticator`

> Copy the binary to a folder in your $PATH. We recommend creating a $HOME/bin/aws-iam-authenticator and ensuring that $HOME/bin comes first in your $PATH. `mkdir -p $HOME/bin && cp ./aws-iam-authenticator $HOME/bin/aws-iam-authenticator && export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin`

> Add $HOME/bin to your PATH environment variable. `echo 'export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin' >> ~/.bashrc`

> Test that the aws-iam-authenticator binary works. `aws-iam-authenticator help`