# kubectl unable to connect with eks after configuration

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubectl, eksctl

configuration

```
aws eks --region us-east-1 update-kubeconfig --name app-cluster
```

```
~ kubectl get svc
error: exec plugin: invalid apiVersion "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1"
```

```
~ kubectl version
error: exec plugin: invalid apiVersion "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1"
```

```
~ kubectl version --client
Client Version: v1.29.2
Kustomize Version: v5.0.4-0.20230601165947-6ce0bf390ce3
```

The version of kubectl in the eks cluster is 1.29
The EKS cluster was created vio `eksctl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue faced me before, It took two days to troubleshoot. Please check the following:

1- your kubectl version is compatible with Kubernetes version. In your case it looks good.

2- the aws cli version is the usually the reason, Upgrade the version of aws cli to latest version, run the command again and it should work.
An [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63116765/aws-cli-update-kubeconfig-not-working-as-expected) related to yours might help you as well.

If you're using a user that is different
From the one that created the cluster, Ensure that your IAM exists in aws auth configmap, this [article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-user-role.html) might help you